# How to add different join in a query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a assignment table:

```
ID     Name     TaskID
A1     John       A
A2     Roy        B
A3     Clair      A1
```

This is TaskID_1 table (all column should be selected):

```
TaskID     Deadline   supervisor   division   letterID   organizer
A           10
B           20
```

This is TaskID_2 table (all column should be selected) :

```
TaskID     Deadline  place_of_arrival     staffID    day_of_shipment
A1          100
A2          200
```

So, I'd like to join in different table.

If the query is (`SELECT * FROM assignment where id ='A3'`) then the Task ID will be A1, so I'd like to join with Task ID2 table.

But if the query is (`SELECT * FROM assignment where id ='A2'`) then the Task ID will be B, so I'd like to join with Task ID1 table.

Is it possible ?
It's something like this (**not a valid SQL query**) :

```
SELECT * FROM assignment 
IF(assignment.TaskID IN (SELECT TaskID FROM TaskID_1))
{ INNER JOIN TaskID_1 ON assignment.TaskID = TaskID_1.TaskID }
else
{ INNER JOIN TaskID_2 ON assignment.TaskID = TaskID_2.TaskID }
WHERE assignment.ID = 'some_variable'
```

nb:

- I am using Code Igniter so the script is in active record
- I don't have the privilege to change the table structure.

Comment: Just  curious, but what is the point of having two TaskID tables with the same definition?

Comment: well, there are more differences i'm not adding all the column. It's gonna be too long.

Comment: Use Union  in your case

Comment: sorry, see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional joins do not exists in sql in general. Either you join a table or you do not, but you have to make up your mind.

What you can do to achive the expected out come is 2 outer joins to the assignment table, or a union of 2 queries that inner join the assignment table to one of the 2 taskid tables. I'll show you the outer join version. In the select list either use coalesce() to return the first non-null value, or list fields from both tables and make the decision in the calling application as to which field's data to use.

```
select a.*, coalesce(t1.deadline, t2.deadline) as deadline from assignment a
left join taskid_1 t1 on a.taskid=t1.taskid
left join taskid_2 t2 on a.taskid=t2.taskid
```

Comment: woah, thank you so much. with some little tweaking I have my expected result.